# Adding Parameters with Stripe Checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, stripe-payments, parameters

I am attempting to add parameters to Stripe Checkout.

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

<% end %>
<%= form_tag charges_path, class: 'stripeform' do %>

    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
            data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
            data-description="Beautiful"
            data-amount="<%= @price*100 %>"
            data-image="<%= image_tag "logo.png" %>"></script>

<% end %>
```

Considering Stripe has its own "submit" button, how would one pass additional parameters?

Comment: Just put your fields inside Checkout's form and they'll get submitted along with the form?

Comment: Composing compound words such as data-name doesn't work. There are restrictions. https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just add extra `<input>` fields inside the form you use for Checkout. They will get posted along with the Stripe token

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="extraParam">
  <input type="text" name="extraParam2">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_XXX"
    data-image="/square-image.png"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-amount="2000">
  </script>
</form>
```

The other solution would be to use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) to retrieve the token in the `token()` callback and then add it as a hidden input in your own form and submit that.